# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'locator')

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

```
//1. Main program
const{ test, expect, Page } = require('@playwright/test');
const{ pageobjectmanager } = require('./pageobjects/pageobjectmanager');

test.describe('Clubbing multiple tests under one', async() => {
        let page=Page;
            
        test.beforeAll(async({ browser }) => {
           page = await browser.newPage();
           await land.goTo();
        });

        test.afterAll(async ({ browser }) =>  {
            browser.close();
        });

        const username = "profile-only-07@test.com";
        const password = "gcomRocks1!";
        const pom = new pageobjectmanager(page);
        const land = pom.getLanding();
        const lg = pom.getLogin();
        const ts = pom.getTOS();

    test('Application Login', async() => { 
        await land.signIn();
        await lg.submitCredentials(username,password);    
    });

    test('Pre-Screen Questionaries', async() => {
        await ts.getTOSButtonsFunction();
        await ts.getAcceptTermsAndConditions();
    });
});


//2. PageObjectManager.js 
const{ landing }=require('./landing')
const{ login }=require('./login')
const{ CACFP }=require('./CACFP')
const{ TOS }=require('./TOS')

class pageobjectmanager {
    constructor(page)
    {
        this.page=page;
        this.landing=new landing(page);
        this.login=new login(page);
        this.cacfp=new CACFP(page);
        this.tos=new TOS(page);
    }

     getLanding()
    {
        return this.landing;
    }

    getLogin()
    {
        return this.login;
    }
    getCACFP()
    {
        return this.cacfp;
    }
    getTOS()
    {
        return this.tos;
    }

};
module.exports={pageobjectmanager}

//3.pageObjectfile.js
const{test,expect}=require('@playwright/test');
class landing{

    constructor(page)
    {
        this.page=page;
        this.signin=page.locator("text='Sign In'");
        this.pagetitle=page.locator("//a[@class='navbar-brand']/span[text()='CNP MIS']");
    }

    async goTo()
    {
        await this.page.goto("https://gcom-nutr-cnpmis-dev-client.azurewebsites.net/landing",{ waitUntil: 'networkidle' });
        await this.pagetitle.waitFor();
        await expect(this.pagetitle).toHaveText("CNP MIS");
    }

    async signIn()
    {
        await this.signin.click();
    }
   
};
module.exports={ landing };
```

I wanted to run the code which is in section 1 in sequence so I used playwright hook functions `test.beforeAll()` and `test.afterAll()` and wrapped the code under `test.describe()`. And passed the browser fixture instead of page so that same page is shared across all the tests (where I can run one continuous flow without opening the new page for every `test()`. while doing so I am getting below error.

```
Node.js v17.3.1
PS C:\Users\govardhana.kj\Playwright> npx playwright test tests/ValidLogin1.spec.js

Running 0 test using 0 worker

=================
 no tests found.
C:\Users\govardhana.kj\Playwright\tests\pageobjects\landing.js:8
        this.signin=page.locator("text='Sign In'");
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'locator')
    at new landing (C:\Users\govardhana.kj\Playwright\tests\pageobjects\landing.js:8:26)
    at new pageobjectmanager (C:\Users\govardhana.kj\Playwright\tests\pageobjects\pageobjectmanager.js:11:22)
    at C:\Users\govardhana.kj\Playwright\tests\ValidLogin1.spec.js:22:19
    at TestTypeImpl._describe (C:\Users\govardhana.kj\Playwright\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\testType.js:130:5)
    at Function.describe (C:\Users\govardhana.kj\Playwright\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\transform.js:269:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\govardhana.kj\Playwright\tests\ValidLogin1.spec.js:5:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Loader._requireOrImport (C:\Users\govardhana.kj\Playwright\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\loader.js:276:14)
    at Loader.loadTestFile (C:\Users\govardhana.kj\Playwright\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\loader.js:164:18)
    at Runner._runFiles (C:\Users\govardhana.kj\Playwright\node_modules\@playwright\test\lib\runner.js:289:44)
```

Comment: `page` has become `undefined`, or the `beforeAll` sets it to `undefined`, but not possible to see from the code how that might have been.  I would suspect that the `describe` block is being called again on each test.  Maybe `page` should be instantiated outside of the `describe`?

Comment: I would use fixtures, and pass them in any test you want:
https://playwright.dev/docs/next/test-fixtures#creating-a-fixture

Navigate using fixtures and then pass them instead of page

Comment: I have declared the pageObejcts before using it in before.All then it started working.